# Prove that $6|(n^2 - 1)$ if $gcd(6,n) = 1$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I'm working through the problems in this book: [Number Theory (Dover Books on Mathematics)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0486682528)  and I came across this problem (title).

here is my working

$gcd(6,n) = 1  \implies 1 =  nx + 6y$  for some $x$ and $y$ (1)

$ 3 |(n^3 - n)  \implies n(n^2-1) = 3k $ for some $k$ (2) (Fermat’s Little Theorem)

Multiplying (1) by $n^2-1$ yields,

$n^2 - 1 = n(n^2 - 1)x + 6y(n^2 -1)$

Subbing (2) back into the equation...

$n^2 - 1 = 3(kx + 2y(n^2-1))$

$\therefore 3|(n^2-1)$

But I can't get $6|(n^2 -1)$. Is it a typo?

Comment: Have you studied modular arithmetic?  This will give you a much easier solution.

Comment: Not yet. The book starts Modular Arithmetic in the next chapter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** $n(n^2-1) = (n-1)n(n+1)$ is a multiple of $3! = 6$

Answer (score 1):

A quick way would be to apply Euler's Theorem: noting that $\varphi(6)=2$. This implies that

$$n^2=n^{\varphi(6)}\equiv1\pmod{6}$$

whenever $\gcd(6,n)=1$. This means that $n^2-1\equiv0\pmod{6}$, which implies your result.

Alternatively, we continue from where you left off. You have already shown that $3\mid(n^2-1)$, so to show that $6\mid(n^2-1)$, you just need to show that $2\mid (n^2-1)$ as well, which is true because $n$ must be odd.

Answer (score 1):

If $gcd(6, n) = 1$,
then $n = 6k\pm 1$
for some $k$
(do you see why?).

Therefore
$n^2
=36k^2\pm 12k +1
$
or
$n^2-1
=36k^2\pm 12k
=12(3k^2\pm k)
$
so
$12 | (n^2-1)$,
not just $6$.